# Correct way of defining option in a type

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I am learning F# and trying to create a type called Person with 4 properties. 2 of them (mother and father) are optional but somehow I am receiving compiler error.

```
type Person = {
    name : string;
    age : int;
    mother: Person option -> Person option;
    father: Person option -> Person option;
}

let defaultPerson = {
    name = ""; 
    age = 0; 
    mother = fun person -> person; 
    father = fun person -> person }

let displayPerson person =
    printfn "Name: %s, Age: %d" person.name person.age

let setName person name = 
    { person with Person.name = name }

let setAge person name = 
    { person with Person.name = name }

let setMother person mother = 
    { person with Person.mother = mother }

let setFather person father = 
    { person with Person.father = father }
```

But when I try following code, it throws a compiler error:

```
let mother1 = { 
    Person.name = "Angelica"; 
    age = 47; 
    mother = Option<Person>.None; //mother = None doesn't work 
    father = Option<Person>.None }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me why `mother` and `father` are defined as **functions**, but you can set them using the `fun` keyword, as you already seem to have discovered:

```
let mother1 = { 
    Person.name = "Angelica"; 
    age = 47; 
    mother = fun _ -> None;
    father = fun _ -> None }
```

Wouldn't the following be a more sensible definition of `Person`?

```
type Person' = {
    Name : string;
    Age : int;
    Mother: Person' option;
    Father: Person' option;
}
```

This would let you define a value like this:

```
let mother2 = { 
    Name = "Angelica"; 
    Age = 47; 
    Mother = None;
    Father = None }
```

Comment: Thank you Mark!, I have defined mother and father as functions, because I would like to set name and age for every mother and father untill I set "None"

Comment: @Reis Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Everything works fine, I just got your idea. I am just a bit confused with types at the moment. Thank you mark